# nodejs zmq - received buffer data than actual message

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I am doing the example of `pubsub` from [this link](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js) and managed to get it work.

server.js:

```
const zmq = require("zeromq")

async function run() {
  const sock = new zmq.Publisher

  await sock.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")
  console.log("Publisher bound to port 3000")

  while (true) {
    console.log("sending a multipart message envelope")
    await sock.send(["kitty cats", "meow!"])
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
  }
}

run()
```

client.js:

```
const zmq = require("zeromq")

async function run() {
  const sock = new zmq.Subscriber

  sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")
  sock.subscribe("kitty cats")
  console.log("Subscriber connected to port 3000")

  for await (const [topic, msg] of sock) {
    console.log("received a message related to:", topic, "containing message:", msg)
  }
}

run()
```

so I expect the log from `client.js` to be:

```
received a message related to: kitty cats containing message: meow!
```

but get this instead:

```
received a message related to: <Buffer 6b 69 74 74 79 20 63 61 74 73> containing message: <Buffer 6d 65 6f 77 21>
```

Is this normal? or is there a way to get back my message in `string` form?

Comment: buffer.toString("utf-8"), e.g. `topic.toString("utf-8")` or `msg.toString("utf-8")`

Comment: if you were to decode the hex in the buffer as a `char` list, then you'd see that each number is a character code. the comment above describes how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to convert a Buffer to string with `toString()` (defaults to `utf-8` encoding)

or you can use [string-decoder](https://nodejs.org/api/string_decoder.html) from nodejs

with `stringDecoder.write(buffer)`

i.e. `stringDecoder.write(topic)`

```
const zmq = require("zeromq")

async function run() {
  const sock = new zmq.Subscriber

  sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")
  sock.subscribe("kitty cats")
  console.log("Subscriber connected to port 3000")

  for await (const [topic, msg] of sock) {
    console.log("received a message related to:", topic.toString("utf=8"), "containing message:", msg.toString("utf-8")
  }
}

run()
```

Comment: Does the **`topic`**-string in `node.js`-wrapper meet the ZeroMQ API (since ever, considers **`topic`**-string (reg'd in the Topic-filter via subscription management *( like `.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, ...)` )* to be a byte-wise,left-edge matched against any of the pre-reg'd Topic-filter strings)? Does the `for await ( const [topic, msg] of sock )` iterator keep the **`msg`** intact & replicates the 1st matched **`topic`**-sub-string, or does it split a binary-copy of the original **`msg`** into a pair of non-overlapping sub-strs `topic` and `msg`,the latter being "shorter" than the original?

Comment: ok that's really two questions - so i'll rephrase for brevity.

**1.** Does the topic string meet the ZeroMQ API? (not sure what this means tbh, the Q is converting a buffer to a string).
**2.** Does the `for await` syntax iterator keep the msg intact (this is known as a `async iterator` - so unsure what it is meant by `binary-copy`

Comment: Ad 1 ) The "topic"-string in the native ZeroMQ API documentation is not a separate string, per-se, it is a left-side string-matching operation performed by the **`PUB/SUB`** distributed-behaviour archetype ( since v2.11+ this archetype executed the "topic"-filtering operations remote, after message delivered on the **`SUB`**-side, v4+ versions started to do this filtering locally, on **`PUB`**-side )

Comment: Ad 2 ) the point was, if the **`(const [topic, msg] of sock)`** operations, controlling the *async iterator* instance, actually chop the message ( for which there is a ZeroMQ Warrant for being delivered as an exact, **binary**-copy of the senders' original ) into disjunct parts - `[topic, msg]`, or if the the `msg`-part returned from the *async iterator* instance always contains the "topic"-string against which it was matched in its "left"-most bytes ( as sent ) and the `topic` is thus yielded twice? Thank you for your clarification of the way this wrapper works. ZeroMQ sender relies on this.